# shuffling card and permutation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, inclusion-exclusion

I have 5 cards. Card labeled i starts in position i. So, card 1 is first, card 2 is second, card 3 is third, etc. I shuffle them. This gives me a random permutation of the cards. What is the probability that none of my cards are now in the same position they started. In other words: what is the probability that (card 1 is not in spot 1 AND card 2 is not in spot 2 AND card 3 is not in spot 3 AND card 4 is not in spot 4 AND card 5 is not in spot 5)?

Comment: For a general treatment, see Wikipedia, Derangements.

Comment: which is the right formula for counting the total rearrangements?

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, card 1 is just as likely to be in positions 2,3,4, or 5.
So we only need to count the permutations like ${*}1{*}{*}{*}$ and multiply
by four.

Assume card 1 is in position 2. 
There are two ways that, in addition,  card 2 ends up in position 1:
$21453$ and $21534$. There are 3 ways card 3 ends up in position 1: 
 $31254$, $31524$, and $31452$, and similarly for card 4 or 5 being in position 1.
 To recap, there are $2+3+3+3=11$ ways with card 1 in position 2.

Multiplying by four shows that the total is 44, so the probability is $44/120=.36666$.

Comment: why there are not 6 ways that card 2 ends up in position 1?

Comment: oh nvm i get it, because card 3 cannot go back to its previous position, same for card 4,5